# Parent's stopPropagation is disabling grandchild's functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal which when open gets this jquery statement:

```
  $(".modal-inner").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

The trouble is, nested within this modal body, I have a child element that I'm using Clipboard.js on so a user may copy text. HTML as follows:

```
 <div class="modal-inner"> <!-- stopPropagation applied to parent -->
   <div class="modal-close" for="modal-1"></div>
     <h1>Let's Connect</h1>
     <i class="e"></i>
     <p>You can reach me at:</p>
     <p class="em">
       <input id="emailToCopy" value="this.email@gmail.com"/>
       <!-- This grandchild's functionality is now disabled -->
       <button class="clip-btn" id="thisClip"  data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#emailToCopy" value="clipBtn">copy email</button>
     </p>
 </div>
```

The stopPropagation on .modal-inner keeps the modal from closing if the user clicks inside. This in turn disables my button which executes a script when clicked. I need this button to bypass the stopPropagation from the parent element.

Answer (score 2):

You could just check if the button is clicked, and stop propagation conditionally

```
$(".modal-inner").on("click", function(e) {

   if ( $(e.target).closest('#thisClip').length > 0 ) { // this is the button
       e.stopPropagation();
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however this solution closes the modal when the button is clicked.

Comment: @user2588166 - oh, I see, you're trying to stop the button from propagating, but not the rest of the modal ? Try it now, with the reversed effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not elegant but I believe will work:

```
$(".modal-inner").on("click", function(e) {

    if (!$("button").is(":hover")) e.stopPropagation();

});
```

Comment: Thanks and same as above unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You may try testing the event target id and tagName:

```js
$('.modal-inner').on("click", function(e) {
  //
  // you may also use:
  //  if ( $(e.target).is('#thisClip') ) {
  //
  
  if (e.target.id = 'thisClip' && e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('You clicked the button: stop propagation');
  } else {
    console.log('You did not click the button');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal-inner"> <!-- stopPropagation applied to parent -->
    <div class="modal-close" for="modal-1"></div>
    <h1>Let's Connect</h1>
    <i class="e"></i>
    <p>You can reach me at:</p>
    <p class="em">
        <input id="emailToCopy" value="this.email@gmail.com"/>
        <!-- This grandchild's functionality is now disabled -->
        <button class="clip-btn" id="thisClip"  data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#emailToCopy" value="clipBtn">copy email</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I failed at phrasing my question as the responses are opposite of what I'm looking to accomplish. The modal body has stopPropagation attached to it when opened. Therefore, the button nested inside that also has a function is affected. I'd like that button to ignore or bypass the modal body's stopPropagation. I'm sorry if that isn't clear in my original question.